# Changing a string into block of five python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I change a string so that every 5 characters there will be a space in between?
However, I do not wish to have space at the beginning or at the end.

for example

```
"Yohomeyoverstack" will be "Yohom eyove rstac k"

"two"  will be "two"
```

Comment: what's your attempt at solving this

Comment: Another version of the ["split a list into evenly sized chunks"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/8881141) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `slicing`

**Ex:**

```
s = "Yohomeyoverstack"
print( " ".join([s[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(s), 5)]) )
```

**Output:**

```
Yohom eyove rstac k
```

Comment: But what if the string have white spaces in it. Like `s = "Yohomeyov  erstack"`. The output will have spaces in the begining and end

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the help of slicing.

```
data = "Yohomeyoverstack"

stripped = "".join(data.split())

splitted = " ".join([stripped[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(stripped), 5)])

print(splitted)
```

This solution will work even if there are whitespaces in the string